# Set value to zero based on user input form condition using javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have created a simple calculator. I have set the user input with if-else condition to show / hide input form fields using radio buttons. Here is the code:

```
    Amount Saved For retirement : Yes <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck"> No <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck">
    <div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden">
        <div class="i_container">
         <div class="i_row">
            <label id="saved_amount_label_id" for="saved_amount_input_id1">Saved Amount For Retirement (₹)</label>
            <span><input class="form-control" name="saved_amount_input_name1" id="saved_amount_input_id1" type="number" step="50000" value="0" min="0" max="10000000" oninput="showValSavedAmount(this.value)" /></span>
         </div>
         
      </div>
      <div class="i_container">
         <div class="i_row">
            <label for="retirement_return_input_id1">Expected Return Percentage (%)</label>
            <span><input class="form-control" name="retirement_return_input_name1" id="retirement_return_input_id1" type="number" value="12" min="5" max="30" step="0.5" oninput="showValRetirementReturn(this.value)" /></span>
         </div>
         
      </div>

    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'hidden';

}
```

I need to set the value back to zero if the condition "NO" has been selected after given some input value in fields set to visible if they clicked "YES".

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cmspsathyaprakash/mfqd7ax4/7/

Comment: Also consider using `onchange` not `onclick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the values to `0` in your else condition

```js
function showValRetirementReturn(){

}
function showValSavedAmount(){

}

function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    else {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('saved_amount_input_id1').value ="0";
document.getElementById('retirement_return_input_id1').value ="0";
}
}
```

```html
Amount Saved For retirement : Yes <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck"> No <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck">
    <div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden">
        <div class="i_container">
         <div class="i_row">
            <label id="saved_amount_label_id" for="saved_amount_input_id1">Saved Amount For Retirement (₹)</label>
            <span><input class="form-control" name="saved_amount_input_name1" id="saved_amount_input_id1" type="number" step="50000" value="0" min="0" max="10000000" oninput="showValSavedAmount(this.value)" /></span>
         </div>
         
      </div>
      <div class="i_container">
         <div class="i_row">
            <label for="retirement_return_input_id1">Expected Return Percentage (%)</label>
            <span><input class="form-control" name="retirement_return_input_name1" id="retirement_return_input_id1" type="number" value="12" min="5" max="30" step="0.5" oninput="showValRetirementReturn(this.value)" /></span>
         </div>
         
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tushar. However i have a small issue with Event listener. Please visit this js fiddle to know better understanding of the issues.  https://jsfiddle.net/cmspsathyaprakash/agfm4etc/3/

Comment: Sure, please add details. Also I added the two empty functions so code could run without errors.

Comment: yes code works as what we expect. but issue is with the ajax results function. Try switching between the Yes and No. The value in result is not getting back to zero after I clicked No

Comment: Thanks Tushar. I solved that issue by adding event listener function to the else condition.